# Isabelle: proof obligation - proving using counterexamples

Tags: isabelle

For an example lemma like this:

```
lemma someFuncLemma: "∀ (e::someType) . pre_someFunc 2 e"
```

which gives the following when using quickcheck:

```
Auto Quickcheck found a counterexample:
  e = - 1
```

or when using Nitpick (which isn't really the main point here):

```
Nitpick found a counterexample:

  Skolem constant:
    e = - 1
```

How can I then use this counterexample to finish the proof?

As you can see, I'm not very familiar with Isabelle and POs.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The presence of a counterexample usually indicates that you won't be able to prove your proposition, except maybe

- the counterexample is spurious;
- the underlying logic is inconsistent.

Comment: Or there is a bug in nitpick/quickcheck. Counterexamples that come out of nitpick/quickcheck do not go through the Isabelle kernel, i.e. just because nitpick/quickcheck tell you something is a counterexample, you do not automatically get an Isabelle theorem that it really is one. If you want that, you will have to prove it yourself. (which will in most cases be possible by simple rewriting)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to prove there exists some `e` such that `pre_someFunc 2 e` is false. You would have to change your lemma to use *exists* instead of *forall*, and prefix your predicate with *not*:

```
lemma "∃e::someType. ¬(pre_someFunc 2 e)"
```

Then you can provide the counter-example using `rule exI[where x=...]` which sets the free variable `x` in `exI` to something. You can look at the definition of `exI` and how `x` is used by clicking it while holding `Ctrl` in Isabelle JEdit.

A simple example:

```
lemma "∃n :: nat. ¬ odd n"
apply (rule exI[where x=2])
apply simp
done
```